# wpf DataGrid change wrapping on cells

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, app.xaml

I have a WPF DataGrid with AutoGenerate Columns. I have been able to override the column headers using code and also force wrapping on the column headers when I shrink the columns.  When I try to force text wrapping on the cells my binding breaks... it shows the same value in every column.

Here is the XAML I am using to format

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
   <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
       <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
           <Setter.Value>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
               </DataTemplate>
           </Setter.Value>
       </Setter>
   </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
<DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
   <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
       <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
           <Setter.Value>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
               </DataTemplate>
           </Setter.Value>
       </Setter>
   </Style>
</DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
```

Again, the ColumnHeaderStyle works fine, but the CellStyle is not working.

Suggestions?

**Update:**

Column headers are set as follows:

```
if (e.Column.Header.ToString() == "Product_Description")
    e.Column.Header = "Product";

if (e.Column.Header.ToString() == "Original_Gross_Weight")
    e.Column.Header = "Orig. Net Wt.";
```

The wrapping of the headers works well.  Just the wrapping of the content does not work.

Comment: If the grid is autogenerating from the properties, property names do not have spaces to wrap on...so what does setting it to `wrap` provide?

Comment: See the update.  Header wrapping works when I override the header in code.

Comment: Ha.  Just saw a typo in the heading text too.  oops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the binding it seems that once one replaces the DataGridCell data style, the full object for for the **row** is placed into the content presenter instead of the current property of the column.

---

It appears you override `AutoGeneratingColumn` so why not simply turn of auto generate and define the columns by hand?

Here is a working version where the text is wrapped for the data:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <model:People x:Key="People">
        <model:Person First="Joe"   Last="Smith"   Phone="303-555 5555" />
        <model:Person First="Mary"  Last="Johnson" Phone="720-555 5555" />
        <model:Person First="Frank" Last="Wright"  Phone="202-555 5555" />
    </model:People>
</Window.Resources>
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          ItemsSource="{StaticResource People}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="First" Binding="{Binding First}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="The Name" Binding="{Binding Last}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Phone Number" Binding="{Binding Phone}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="TextWrapping"
                            Value="Wrap" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>

        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Yep.  Might as well.  Once I manually type all the stuff for headers in code, I might as well do it in XAML.  That will allow me to customize everything in one place.  Thank You for the thorough example.